# Does sheetson api free plan only allows max 24 rows per sheet?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, google-sheets, array-map

I am using [sheetson](https://sheetson.com/#pricing) free plan which mentioned unlimited row per sheet. But when I fetch the api from google sheet, I only received 24 rows. I can't figure out why didn't retrieve full list of data which is 32. Is that limit from the google sheet api itself or the wrong information on sheetson website. Please help.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KSRJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeo5J.png)

Comment: I found the solution in their (documentation)[https://docs.sheetson.com/manage-data/paginate-filter/] page. I was caught by surprise and recklessly posted the question here. But, I will delete the question, just in case for other Sheetson user out there like me.

Answer (score 0):

as you said you have to pass `params = {"limit": "100"}` when you call requests.get. There's a limit of 100 rows that you can retrieve at once, to overcome it use `{"skip": "100"}` and it will skip the first 100 rows. Answering in case someone has the same doubt we both had at some point